# Good book about SharePoint web services?

Tags: web-services

I'll be frank the MS documentation for MS web services is terrible / non existent. Do any books exist or web sites that provide full detailed documentation of the usage of SharePoint exposed web services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything specific you are looking for?

Here is something on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878586%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Typically when trying something I haven't done before I'll open up WebServices Studio (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/webservicestudio20) and make the calls to see what is passed and returned.  This tool makes it pretty easy to get a good look at what is available and how you work with it.

Comment: @Mike, yes specifically looking for a way to update a list item, based on a field other than ID.

Comment: Unfortunately you need to use the ID to update a specific record versus more of a query based update.  If you need to update multiple records based on a condition then you would need to execute a GetListItems call with the query and then iterate through and prepare an update call for the batch.